# How can I repair GRUB in a dual boot with Windows 8.1?

Tags: grub2

My Thinkpad runs Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.4 on dual boot. But since I tried Puppy Linux via a bootable USB stick my Ubuntu does not show up, Windows 8.1 just boots. Any solutions?

My BIOS is UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is an Ubuntu live cd with Internet connected. Go through this link:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and follow the instructions. I recently recovered grub on my triple boot system after an Ubuntu upgrade that didn't went as planned.